# Counting the number of bits of value 1 in an array - Understanding the code behind it (C)

Tags: c, arrays, count, bit

> The following code counts the number of bits of value '1' in the array
>   'buf':

```
long bit_count(long *arr, int size)
{
    int w,b;
    unsigned long word=0;
    long n = 0;

    for(w = 0; w<size ; w++){
        word = arr[w];
        while(word != 0){
            n += word & 1;
            word >>= 1;
        }
    }
    return n;
}

int main() {

     char buf[] = {"There is always one more!"};         //(1)
     int length = strlen(buf)>>3;                        //(2)
     long *a = (long*) (buf + length);                   //(3)
     //char * b = (char *)a; // this is a comment.       //(4)
     int len = strlen((char*)a);                         //(5)
     long total_count = bit_count((long*) buf, length);  //(6)
     *a = (*a) & (((long)1<<(len*8))-1);                 //(7)
     char *c = (char*)a;                                 //(8)
     total_count += bit_count(a,1);                      //(9)
     printf("bits number %ld\n",total_count);            //(10)

    return 0;
}
```

That's my understanding of the code: (please correct me if I'm wrong, I want to understand it at the deepest level)

In line (2) they compute the number of letters in buf which is 25 and it's equivalent to 25 bytes. cause the size of char is 1 byte.
then by shifting that number 3 bits right they dividing it by 8,
8 defines 8 bytes = 1 long type. **so how many "longs" this buf array contains.**

line (3) - 'a' points to a value that contains the casting of the remainder of buf to `(long *)` - in line (4) I saw that b* value will be "!" which is exactly the remainder of 1 byte in the array. **but I don't really understand the casting to `(long *)`** the value I'm getting is different if I check

```
long check = (long) (buf + length);
```

so what exactly happens when I do - `{(long*)buf}`  is my first question.

in line (6) I count the bits in the first part of the array (by longs)
and in line (9) I count the bits in the remainder.

what I don't understand is - what happens in line (7)?

Comment: I can't be bothered to analyze this kind of "tricky" code just now, so I'll just offer this comment: Someone has gone to a significant amount of trouble here to write code which is (a) less portable, (b) harder for the reader to understand, and (c) *maybe* a little more efficient.  I commend you for your attempt to understand this code, but my approach would be to walk away -- I've got better things to do.

Comment: I guess it's deliberate cause its a code from an old exam lol

Comment: [don't put line numbers like that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7119/230282). It makes it hard to read and harder for people who want to try your code. If really necessary put them in comments after the line

Comment: "at the deepest level". Ahh, the old well of doom.

Comment: @phuclv I edited the post, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing tricky about the code, but it is not very good. Actually, it is very bad, and not because of style but because it corrupts memory.

```
(2)  int length = strlen(buf)>>3;
```

This line calculates the whole number of `long` objects that fit in the string, assuming that `long` is eight bytes (`/ sizeof(long)` should be used instead of `>>3`) and that `int` is big enough to hold the number (`size_t` should be used instead of `int`).

```
(3)  long *a = (long*) (buf + length);
```

This seems to intend to set `a` to point to the fragment at the end of the string that is not long enough to contain another `long` object. However, because `length` is a number of `long` objects and `buf` acts as a pointer to `char`, its arithmetic is incorrect. It calculates `buf` plus `length` `char` objects when it intends to calculate `buf` plus `length` `long` objects. It ought to use `(long *) buf + length`. Also, it assumes that a `char *` with arbitrary alignment can be sensibly converted to a `long *`, which is not guaranteed by the C standard.

```
(5)  int len = strlen((char*)a);
```

This calculates the number of bytes in the fragment. It is a waste because the code previously calculated the length of the string. It could have saved that length and taken the quotient and remainder modulo the size of `long` rather than calling `strlen` again.

```
(6)  long total_count = bit_count((long*) buf, length);
```

This calculates the number of bits set in the main portion of the buffer, that is, the portion that is treated as some whole number of `long` objects. As with the earlier conversion, it assumes that a `char *` can be converted to a `long *`, and, further, the routine it calls uses that pointer to read `long` objects from an object not defined as an array of `long`, thus violating C aliasing rules.

```
(7)  *a = (*a) & (((long)1<<(len*8))-1);
```

Recall that `a` points to some number of trailing bytes in the string. `(long)1<<(len*8)` moves a bit to just above that number of bytes, assuming bytes are eight bits (`CHAR_BIT` should be used instead of `8`). (For example, if there are two bytes, this creates the value 10000<sub>16</sub>.) Then subtracting one creates a bit mask for the bytes (FFFF<sub>16</sub> in the example). Then `*a` attempts to read a `long` from end of the string, after which applying the mask with `&` reduces the value read to just the bytes in the string. This not only violates C’s aliasing rules again but also reads outside the memory of `buf`, which has undefined behavior. Finally, the statement writes the updated value to `*a`, which is even worse—if you got away with reading outside of `buf`, now the code is writing outside of `buf`, causing corruption somewhere unknown.

```
(8)  char *c = (char*)a;
```

This line is useless since `c` is never used.

```
(9)  total_count += bit_count(a,1);
```

This counts the number of bits set in the `long` that was updated in (7).

In the `bit_count` routine, we find the code is counting bits one-by-one. This is absurd. Violating the C rules about aliasing might have made sense to gain some performance benefit of processing whole `long` objects instead of individual `char` objects if the specific C implementation being used allowed the aliasing with unaligned addresses. But this code just does bit-by-bit processing; it does not gain any advantage from some bit-count (also known as population-count) instruction on the processor.

Furthermore, the `bit_count` routine recognizes that it ought to use `unsigned long` for the bit count, as it defines `word` as `unsigned long`. But it fails to recognize it ought to have used `unsigned long` throughout, as the `long` could have a trap representation that would cause the code to fail.

It also defines `b` without ever using it.

Comment: You beat me to it. :-) Just a few notes: `bit_count` should really take a pointer-to-const, as in `const long *arr` (better: `const unsigned long *arr` or even `const unsigned char *arr`). The `size` parameter and the return value should both be `size_t`. Line (3) is the first point where things go south (undefined behavior due to the creation of a misaligned pointer). Better alternatives for counting bits: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive

Comment: (6) is NOT a violation of aliasing rules, since `char` is always allowed to alias anything. Otherwise, great writeup.

Comment: @o11c: `char` can alias anything. `long` cannot alias `char`. It is not two-way. C 2011 (N1570) 6.5 7 says an object shall have its value accessed only by an expression with a type compatible with the object’s type, a character type, and some other cases involving signs and aggregates. So a character type can access any object. But a `long` type cannot access a character object.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ah, but it only has an effective type only because it's declared. If it were allocated, it's impossible to gain an effective type by storing `char`. So `char *a = malloc(4); float f = *(float *)a; int i = *(int *)a;` is legal.

Comment: @o11c: (a) The code in the question does not do this, so your comment is not relevant to it. (b) The rule in the C standard says that an object shall have its stored value accessed only by certain types. Only one category of those it lists, character types, does not require the object to have an effective type. Therefore, if an object does not have an effective type, accessing its stored value via any type other than a character type violates the rule.